# sql server 2005 32 bit on win 2003 64 bit using only 2 gb

Tags: sql-server-2005, memory-management

We have sql 2005 32 bit running on win 2003 64 bit box containing 5 gb RAM.
Is there a way that sql starts using more than 2 gb? some switch or some setting in sql server?

When I go to my sql server properties and try to increase the max server memory to > 2GB, it reverts back to old 2 GB.

Thanks,
Anand

---

**Correction** - Guys: I never noticed that the value mentioned in SQL Server config is in MB. Really very stupid of me - but when you assume things, you turn blind to even the most obvious things. I was assuming the value mentioned over there is in bytes - saw the config screen about 10 times and never really noticed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Slava Oks article: [Enabling AWE settings for SQL Server 32 bit edition in WOW](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101193003/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2006/04/12/575152.aspx). It can be done.

And your licensing team is talking rubbish about 32/64 bit license issues. See the [licensing FAQ.](https://web.archive.org/web/20221021185242/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019) You can mix and match x86/x64 licenses for both Processor and CAL. Unless you've shot yourself in the foot by using Workgroup edition where you can only go to 3Gb anyway. So AWE won't work anyway...

Comment: In Slava Oks article, there is a hyperlink to microsoft site. There it is clearly written   

Support for AWE is available only in the SQL Server 2005 Enterprise, Standard, and Developer editions and only applies to 32-bit operating systems.    

Also, regarding the licensing issue - do you mean to say if I have a 32 bit sql 2005 license, I can download and install sql 2005 64 bit?

Comment: Licensing: yes, unless you have Workgroup edition. Memory: AWE is enabled in *SQL Server*, Have you tried it?

Comment: Once enabled, don't expect to see the memory usage through Task Manager though. When AWE is on, SQL server process shows memory usage around 200MB. However, Windows/system memory is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the 'Use AWE to allocate memory' checkbox?

See [Enabling AWE Memory for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190673.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: From the same link - 

AWE is not required and cannot be configured on 64-bit operating systems.

Comment: Is that on a 64 bit OS, or the 64 bit version of SQL? Is t he option available to be configured, and does anything happen if you do so? And in any case, can you not install a 64-bit edition?

Comment: Hm, the option is there on my Win 7 x64 install. Whether it works, I'm not sure..

Comment: OS = 64 bit, SQL = 32 bit   
Option is enabled for configuration - but it does not change. Organization has license for 32 bit sql 2005. I was told by our licensing team that replacing it with 64 bit sql license is not free.